# Merge Join wrong output (full outer join)

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a merge join problem. I have two tables to join:

**table1:**

```
year , environment , population with values 
------------------------------------------    
2000 , rural , x1     
2000, urbain , x2     
2005, rural , x3 ...etc
```

**table2:**

```
year , environment , poverty_rate
---------------------------------
2000 , rural , y1     
2000, urbain , y2     
2005, ... etc
```

I did a merge join transformation (full outer join) and the output is something like:

```
year, environment, population, poverty_rate 
-------------------------------------------
2005 , rural , x3 , NULL     
2005 , urbain, x4, y4     
NULL, NULL, NULL , y3
```

Can someone please help me find out what went wrong with this? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please show the SQL you used.

Comment: Also, please post what the results you want given your sample data.

Comment: i used the merge join transformation in SSIS 
and what i want is a table that has in each row the year th e environment and both poverty rate and population when both values exist and NULL for the one that doesn't when it's the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming year and environment are the columns that 1 and 2 have in common with each other and assuming you want to display the population and poverty rate only if those two values match then you might want to try this:

```
SELECT t1.year, t1.environment, t1.population, t2.poverty_rate
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.year = t2.year AND t1.environment = t2.environment
```

If you want all records from table1 and only those that match from table2, try this:

```
SELECT t1.year, t1.environment, t1.population, t2.poverty_rate
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.year = t2.year AND t1.environment = t2.environment
```

Comment: thank you for your response but what i need is a full join. so i think replacing LEFT / INNER by FULL does the job .. doesn't it ?

Comment: it did work thnx again .. i wonder why it didn't with the ssis transformation :/